# Выбор каждый раз нового элемента из массива

Tags: javascript

Вывод случайного элемента регулируется событием. При каждом вызове элемент выбирается один и тот же, если использовать подобную понятную конструкцию:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

alert( arr[rand] );
```

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы выбранный элемент каждый раз менялся?

Comment: нужно выполнять `var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);` **каждый** раз перед `arr[rand]`

Answer (score 1):

Ну почему же один и тот же? Разные:

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

setInterval(function(){
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  console.log( arr[rand] );
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно удалять обработанный элемент из массива:

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

while (arr.length) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  console.log(arr[rand]);
  arr.splice(rand, 1);
}
```